# How to search for rows with same column value and insert row if it is not present?

Tags: python, r, bash

I have the following dataset:

```
  CVSO Band   Period       pvalue
1    4    R 1.063372 5.383864e-03
2    4    V 1.652512 1.543246e-17
3   27    V 6.114795 2.174296e-12
4   24    I 7.163776 1.014593e-17
5   24    R 7.164236 0.000000e+00
6   24    V 7.171452 3.342914e-14
```

For each value in the first column, I would like to search whether Band I, R and V exist. For example, in my dataset, 4 only has Band R and V, whereas 24 has all three bands. If one or more of the bands do not exist, I would like to add an NA row such that I get the following output:

```
  CVSO Band   Period       pvalue
1    4    I       NA           NA
2    4    R 1.063372 5.383864e-03
3    4    V 1.652512 1.543246e-17
4   27    I       NA           NA
5   27    R       NA           NA
6   27    V 6.114795 2.174296e-12
7   24    I 7.163776 1.014593e-17
8   24    R 7.164236 0.000000e+00
9   24    V 7.171452 3.342914e-14
```

Comment: Are all of these tags relevant here?

Comment: I have been implementing my code using these three languages. I was hoping to find a solution in any of the tagged languages. This is my first time using StackExchange. If you think that I should add/remove tags, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Using R) Here's a possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
lookup <- c("I", "R", "V")
res <- setDT(df)[, .SD[match(lookup, Band)] , by = CVSO][, Band := lookup]
res
#    CVSO Band   Period       pvalue
# 1:    4    I       NA           NA
# 2:    4    R 1.063372 5.383864e-03
# 3:    4    V 1.652512 1.543246e-17
# 4:   27    I       NA           NA
# 5:   27    R       NA           NA
# 6:   27    V 6.114795 2.174296e-12
# 7:   24    I 7.163776 1.014593e-17
# 8:   24    R 7.164236 0.000000e+00
# 9:   24    V 7.171452 3.342914e-14
```